# Ant scp task not working, even with jsch on ant/lib

Tags: java, ant, build, scp, task

I need to copy a war file via scp.

I have added the `jsch-0.1.42.jar` to `$ANT_HOME/lib` but I'm still getting this error:

> Cause: the class
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp
>   was not found.
>           This looks like one of Ant's optional components.

This is the result of running `ant -diagnostics` just in case:

http://gist.github.com/320859

Comment: you have jsch on the classpath twice, pick one jsch-0.1.29.jar (153401 bytes)
jsch-0.1.42.jar (185746 bytes)

Comment: yeah, it doesn't work with either of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This looks like your problem, from the top of the diagnostics:

**optional tasks : not available**

Your $ANT_HOME/lib directory is missing ant-jsch.jar, which is where your missing class comes from.

I'm not sure how this happened - I always install Ant from the ZIP file on the [download site](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), which includes all the optional tasks.  If you installed Ant from a Linux package, try checking to see if there is a separate package for the optional tasks.

Once you get the optional tasks installed, I would delete the old version of jsch.jar as @trashgod suggests.

Comment: If you're using the 'ant' bundled with MacOSX Lion 10.7+, it does not ship with ant-jsch.jar.  Downloading a copy of the official ant and copying the ant-jsch.jar into your ~/.ant/lib/ along with the jsch.jar itself fixed this for me.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and fixed it!
Remember, you need **BOTH** `ant-jsch.jar` (native from ant or java installation) and updated `jsch` (in my case it was `jsch-0.1.46.jar`) in ant lib dir.

You need to load the newest `jsch.jar` from http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ and add to libs folder (but not replace `ant-jsch.jar`).

The mistake a lot of developers do:

1. `ant-jsch.jar` out of date (in this case <scp> task is unknown for ant)
2. Adjust libraries versions, so `ant-jsch.jar` and `jsch` are compatible.
3. `jsch` not exists or out of date in ant lib dir
4. Native `ant-jsch.jar` replaced with `jsch` (i did it...)

In last 2 cases ant knows *scp* command, but says it is not available.

Comment: And if things still don't work, as it happened to me, note that there are version incompatibilities. Upgrade ant, ensure ant-jsch present, and upgrade jsch to latest.

Comment: Does not help when using `mvn antrun:run`. Trying to use both ant-jsch-1.9.2 andjsch-0.1.54 but it gives error.

Answer (score 0):

I added ant-jsch and jsch dependencies in maven pom.xml or including those two jars in build solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following command:

```
 sudo yum install ant-jsch.noarch
```