# Loading JSCH Library from local lib directory in ant build.xml

Tags: ant

I can do SCP task while i add jsch-0.1.44.jar to ant/lib directory.But i want to load from the local lib dir and add it to classpath.Could you please help

Answer (score 1):

The built-in tasks have limited options for customizing the classpath.

1) Place your custom jars in the ${user.home}/.ant/lib directory

```
/home/mark/.ant
└── lib
    ├── ivy.jar
    └── jsch.jar
```

This is where I install jars that are my personal extensions to the standard ANT distro

2) Supply the location of the jar directory on the commandline

```
ant -lib /path/to/jsh/jar
```

3)
You could try to declare a new task as recommended here:

- [specifying classpath for built-in ant tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536140/specifying-classpath-for-built-in-ant-tasks)